# Why websocket return me nothing and 2probe return only 3(not 3probe)

Tags: parsing, websocket

I'm connecting to websocket:

```
wss://allapteki.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

In Chrome Inspector when get something on http://allapteki.ru i see request:

```
42["get_towns_list",""]
```

and some response. But when i do it *by hands* in websocket plugin for Chrome i get nothing.

2probe command give me *3*(but not *3probe* as in Chrome Inspector). So websocket is OK(or not). But it looks like some security don't let me get info. Why it happens? Cookies? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that. Problem was in https, so socketIO client have to use 443 port instead of 80.

Comment: Lisovkij I know it's been long but I have a question or two about this project